# Image saving to SD card overwriting existing file

Tags: android, bitmap, save

I am successfully saving an Image on button click to the SD card in a folder.

The problem I am having is that the image is overwriting the existing image that has previously saved if I save more than 1 file because the file name is the same so it overwrites the exiting image.

Would there be any way I would be able to make it so when the image saves, it saves with a different name each time so it doesn't overwrite?

Thanks in advance!

Here's what I have so far:

```
OutputStream output;

        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        String time = now.toString();

        // Retrieve the image from the res folder
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap1 = drawable.getBitmap();

        // Find the SD Card path
        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        // Create a new folder in SD Card
        File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/Wallpapers/");
        dir.mkdirs();

        // Create a name for the saved image
        File file = new File(dir, "Wallpaper"+ time );

        // Show a toast message on successful save
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wallpaper saved with success!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {

            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
            bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
String time = now.toString();
```

and get the time at which you're trying to save the file.

Then, attach it to the end of the filename. 
This way, your files will never have the same name, but will always have the same prefix.

To check if a directory exists,

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydirectory");
if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
    // do something here
}
```

However, devices without SD card won't work as expected.

Comment: I've updated my code so you can see what it looks like now, it still isn't working for some odd reason. It only works when I specifically change the file name?

Comment: I think it's because you're making the same directory everytime. Cehck if the directory exists and mkdir only if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

```
Would there be any way I would be able to make it so when the image saves, 
it saves with a different name each time so it doesn't overwrite?
```

yes, you well need to check file with same name is already available in directory or not before saving it using `File.exists()` . do it as:

```
   File file = new File(dir, "Wallpaper.jpg");
   if(file.exists()){
        // assign different name to file
    }
   else{
         // file not present with same name
    }
```

Comment: there's no need to check if file exists, and assign a new name to it. Look at my answer